# How to speed up calculation of sum of weights between edges in graph dataset

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, graph-theory

Versions:

- Python 3.10.8
- Numpy 1.22.3

I am currently trying to implement algebraic multigrid coarsening from "Sadrfaridpour, Ehsan, Talayeh Razzaghi, and Ilya Safro. "[Engineering fast multilevel support vector machines](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10994-019-05800-7)." Machine Learning 108 (2019): 1879-1917." in python.

I have a dataset that is currently represented as a graph, with each point having an edge between it and its 10 nearest neighbors.

I have a list of points that are considered "important". There is a two step process for determining which points are important, and at this step of my program I've already finished the first step and calculated "primary" important points. I want to now move on to the second step and calculate "secondary" important points, which requires calculating the sum of weights between each point in my dataframe and any of the important points.

So for instance, I have the following points that I've determined are "important":

```
importantPoints = [2, 567, 81]
```

I also have two numpy arrays: both are shaped as (n*10) matrices, so each row represents a point in the dataset and each column is it's K-nearest neighbor.

The Neighbor Matrix has the index of each point that is a neighbor:

Neighbor Matrix:

| Neighbor 1 | Neighbor 2 | Neighbor 3 | ---- |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Point 81 | Point 3 | Point 256 |  |
| Point 1 | Point 56 | Point 427 |  |

The Weight Matrix consists of the weight on the edge between each neighbor point, so for instance row 0 column 1 would be the weight of the edge between point 0 and it's closest neighbor.

Weight Matrix:

| Neighbor 1 | Neighbor 2 | Neighbor 3 | ---- |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.99 | 0.5 | 0.38 |  |
| 0.87 | 0.56 | 0.22 |  |

What I have tried to do is the following:

```
 for i in range(KNeighbors.shape[0])
    neighbors = np.argwhere(np.isin(KNeighbors[i], importantPoints)).ravel()
    sumWeights = np.take(Weights[i], neighbors).sum()
```

In the above code, I first test if the important points are in the list of neighbors, use "argwhere" to find the index where these points are, then find the corresponding weight in the weight matrix and sum them up. This code works but its much too slow.

I have looked into vectorizing the code, but the problem is that after the weights are summed I perform a calculation on the value to see if the current point should be added to the "importantPoints" list, and that means that the point will be used in the next calculation of sumWeights.

I'm sure this is not the most efficient way to do this, so I would appreciate any advice on how to re-write the code or re-formulate it to run a bit faster.

Comment: " the sum of weights between each point in my dataframe and any of the important points."  Do you mean the sum of edge weights on the cheapest path from the point and all the important points, or just the closest important point, or something else?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, the sum of edge weights between the point in question and all important points. We're only interested in the edge between a given point and the important points, not the path between them - this calculation is just to test which points are "well connected" to important points.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was to replace that np.argwhere and np.isin with a dictionary of boolean values.

```py
indices = [i for i in range(len(points))]
pointsDict = {k:0 for k in indices}

for s in importantPoints:
    if s in pointsDict.keys():
        pointsDict[s] = 1
```

Then when I wanted to sum the weights, I could instead iterate through the neighbors and check if their dictionary value was 1.

```py
for i in range(KNeighbors.shape[0]):
    sumSeeds = 0
    for j in range(len(KNeighbors[i])):
        if seedDict[KNeighbors[i,j]] == 1:
            sumSeeds = sumSeeds + Weights[i,j]
```

It still feels a bit clunky, but this is significantly faster than trying to search through every list in the KNeighbors matrix.